# Should I have a delay between sending packets?

Tags: java, udp

I have an application that is sending UDP packets to a receiver, should I have a delay between each packet being sent, to avoid overwhelming the receiver, if I do, how do I set the delay time?

note: I am sending a text file over an unreliable network.

```
        for(int x = 0; x < len; x++)
        {
                send_msg(packet);
                Thread.sleep(200); //Should I have this?   
        }
```

Comment: Why do you think the server needs a delay?  If the network is unreliable, how do you get notified when the server does not receive a packet?  If you need reliable transport, why are you using UDP and not TCP?

Comment: @JimGarrison I am developing reliable data transfer over UDP, so the receiver will be sending acknowledgments back, I was thinking that, while the receiver is handling a packet then the packets immediately following wont be received, since it will still be processing the first arriving packet.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel?  Does TCP not provide what you need?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, it does. I'm just programming for fun and would like to do it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Let the OS to handle timings for you. Sending is blocking, so it will rely on OS buffers and related thing. PAckets will be either delivered to serer or lost, but as soon as they are delivered - then the peer will be notified. It may postpone processing or put packets to the queue.